# Java: How to convert alpha numeric string to Integer and from the Integer to same alpha numeric string?

Tags: java

I'm trying to convert a alphanumeric string to a Integer and from the Integer need to produce the same alpha numeric string.

Below is my code. Is their any better approach to achieve it?

```
     Map<Character, String> lettersToNumbers = new HashMap<Character, String>();
    lettersToNumbers .put('1', "01");
    lettersToNumbers .put('2', "02");
    lettersToNumbers .put('3', "03");
    lettersToNumbers .put('4', "04");
    lettersToNumbers .put('5', "05");
    lettersToNumbers .put('6', "06");
    lettersToNumbers .put('7', "07");
    lettersToNumbers .put('8', "08");
    lettersToNumbers .put('9', "09");
    lettersToNumbers .put('0', "00");
    lettersToNumbers .put('A', "10");
    lettersToNumbers .put('B', "11");
    lettersToNumbers .put('C', "12");
    lettersToNumbers .put('D', "13");
    lettersToNumbers .put('E', "14");
    lettersToNumbers .put('F', "15");
    lettersToNumbers .put('G', "16");
    lettersToNumbers .put('H', "17");
    lettersToNumbers .put('I', "18");
    lettersToNumbers .put('J', "19");
    lettersToNumbers .put('K', "20");
    lettersToNumbers .put('L', "21");
    lettersToNumbers .put('M', "22");
    lettersToNumbers .put('N', "23");
    lettersToNumbers .put('O', "24");
    lettersToNumbers .put('P', "25");
    lettersToNumbers .put('Q', "26");
    lettersToNumbers .put('R', "27");
    lettersToNumbers .put('S', "28");
    lettersToNumbers .put('T', "29");
    lettersToNumbers .put('U', "30");
    lettersToNumbers .put('V', "31");
    lettersToNumbers .put('W', "32");
    lettersToNumbers .put('X', "33");
    lettersToNumbers .put('Y', "34");
    lettersToNumbers .put('Z', "35");

        StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();
    String covertToInteger = "FR1234".toUpperCase();
     for (Character ch : covertToInteger.toCharArray()){
            sb.append(lettersToNumbers.get(ch));
        }

System.out.println(sb.toString());

String integertoalphanumeric= sb.toString();
int i=0;
for(;i<abc.length();){

    for (Entry<Character, String> entry : lettersToNumbers.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getValue().equals(abc.substring(i, i+2))) {
            System.out.print(entry.getKey());
        }
    }
    i=i+2;

}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to give more information than this. What is your input? Where to check the String and Integer for?

Comment: What is the mathematical relationship between `3456` and `1234`?    Prepending and removing the `FR` should be simple enough.

Comment: It isn't a reversible function.  You lose information "FR" when you convert to an integer, and unless you save it somehow, you can't reverse the action.  If you need this kind of control, I would advise you to write a class that handles that sort of logic and keeps it consistent.

Comment: An `int` value can only store ~4 billion different values. You can perform the encoding any way you like, however you can't change this. The question is, what else would you like to be able to to encode, without this information there is not way to know what is the best solution.

Comment: I have tried.  1) Encoding the string to bytes then convert the bytes to integer

Comment: in my opinion it works only in one way

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are talking about the `Integer` type, then what you are trying won't work.

Lets assume we restrict ourselves to 6 character alphanumeric strings, as per your example.   There are 62 (Latin) alphanumeric characters: 10 digits, 26 uppercase letters and 26 lowercase letters.

The total number of distinct 6 character alphanum strings is 62<sup>6</sup> == 56800235584.  But there are only 2<sup>32</sup> == 4294967296 distinct values that an `int` / `integer` can represent.  That's an order of magnitude too small.

Thus, it is *mathematically impossible* to come up with an encoding that can represent all possible 6 character alphanum strings as distinct `int` values.

(And if you use `long` instead of `int`, then 11 character strings are too long.)